# give Excel file as a link to download in jsp page

Tags: excel, jsp

How can I give a link to user to download an excel file link on JSP?
my excel will be stored under Web-INF , one folder above my JSP page.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: On a server that is intended to execute jsp or just on a file server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="<%=this.getServletContext().getContextPath() %>/test.xls">Sample Excel File</a>
```